# INSERT INTO command not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-ce

Before I start, I'll let you know that I tried everything that has already been suggested on previous questions and other websites before I considered posting a question myself. As it happens, nothing seems to work and I'm just about fed up with this.

As some background information, this is for my Computing A2 project, so I'm kind of stuck for time now - i.e. I can't be changing loads of my code ideally.

Anyway, onto the issue...
I'm using SQLCe in my code to read from various tables and write to one. So far, the code for reading from the tables works fine, so that's any connection issues out the way first. The piece of code I am struggling with is as follows:

```
        string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.BookingSystemDatabaseConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                string commandStr = "INSERT INTO bookings(username, room, time) VALUES(@username, @room, @time)";
                SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand(commandStr);
                //Passes parameters into SQL command.
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", StaticUser.StudentUser.username);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("room", roomBox.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("time", timeBox.Text);
                //Executes SQL command. Returns the number of affected rows (unecessary for my purposes; a bi-product if you will).
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Could not write new booking to database. This is likely because the database cannot be reached.", "Error");
                Program.AccessError = true;
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

This is just one of the many ways I have tried to combat the issue I am having. I have also explored:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("username", StaticUser.StudentUser.username));
```

to pass the parameters...and another method which escapes me now (using ".Value = StaticUser.StudentUser.username" I think). Furthermore, I have tried using a 'using' statement for the command to save me closing the connection myself (I will probably end up using a solution that uses 'using'). Finally (albeit this isn't a chronological recollection), I tried:

```
SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO bookings(username, room, time) VALUES(@username, @room, @time)", myConnection)
```

Again, of course, to no avail.

To highlight the actual symptoms of the issue I am having: The code appears to run fine; stepping through the full method I have pasted above shows that no error is being caught (of course, the message box does not appear - I realised afterwards that stepping through was arguably an unnecessary procedure) and in the other methods I have touched on, the same thing happens. The issue, then, is that the table 'bookings' is not actually being updated.

So, my question, why?

---

I didn't do the obvious and check the Debug folder for an updated database.

Comment: The way that you are adding `Parameters is fine myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` so what actually is the problem / issue you are facing Michael..?

Comment: The table 'bookings' is not being written to at all. No errors, just there are no new fields in the table after running the procedure.

Comment: have you checked to make sure that you have `GRANT rights` to do the update..? also if the MessageBox is not showing does it hit the `catch`  part of your code..?

Comment: I stepped through, the code doesn't catch any errors. In what situation would I need to use `GRANT rights`?

Comment: Look for a copy of the database file in your bin/debug folder...

Comment: can you clarify for us that all the Variables have Values when you step thru.. the code itself looks perfectly fine in regards to how you have built the Insert Command Query..

Comment: @ErikEJ -_- Please don't let it be this simple.

Comment: Sorry guys. It was just that simple

Comment: @MichaelDipper Could you write down what the answer(as an answer to this question) was and mark it as such?

Comment: It always is, use full path in connection string, and preferably do not include the sdf file in your project (or at least set build action to None)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the advice. Would you recommend using the code I pasted above, or one using 'using' that achieves the same task?

Comment: If you use using, no need to close explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a copy of the database file in your bin/debug folder. 
Use full path in connection string, and preferably do not include the sdf file in your project (or at least set build action to None)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean about the connection string. As it stands, it refers to app.config where the full path is stored. Is this not okay? Thanks for all your help by the way :D

Comment: Never mind, I understand what you mean now. Put the database (.sdf) somewhere then have the hard file path...makes sense. The reason I haven't done that is because the project is mainly on my memory stick - I work on it at home and at school - and the drive letter changes.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not defining a connection for the command
try

```
mycommand.connection = connectiostring;
```